# Piping Terminal command to Gedit for further editing

Tags: 12.04, command-line, gedit

I have a complex command in my terminal window which I would like to edit further e. g.

```
echo "This is a complex command I want to edit in an editor"
```

How can I pipe this line of code - not the output but the actual code - to e.g. Gedit for further editing? Something along the lines of this solution, just for a GUI based editor: [http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/1446/rapidly-invoke-an-editor-to-wri‌​te-a-long-complex-or-tricky-command](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/1446/rapidly-invoke-an-editor-to-wri%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bte-a-long-complex-or-tricky-command)

Please note that I'm specifically looking for a way to edit in an external editor.

Comment: ^^ Read my answer there, it does exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: Yes, it is a good answer ^^

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`bash`, `zsh`, and `ksh` (including it's derivatives) have this very neat built in command `fc`, which opens an editor for altering your previous command. If the variable `FCEDIT` is not set, by default it will call the editor set in `EDITOR`; if the variable `EDITOR` is not set, by default it will call `nano`.

What you can do, is to set `FCEDIT=/usr/bin/gedit`. Now there's the trick: you run a long command, you decide you want to change it, so immediately after you run it call `fc`. That will spawn `gedit` window with your command right there ready for altering. Once you're done altering, save and exit as if you normally would.

The disadvantage ? It will leave a trail of unnecessary gtk messages in terminal. Personally, I use `vim` or `nano` command line editors rather than gedit - those don't leave any trace , besides they can be used in `TTY` not just in GUI environment. I strongly suggest you switch to `nano` as it is one of the easiest command line text editors.

**Extra note** in `bash`, you can do the same with the command line *your are currently editing* with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> - <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>; you can have the same behavior in `zsh` adding to your `.zshrc`

```
autoload -z edit-command-line
zle -N edit-command-line
bindkey '^XE' edit-command-line # binds CTRL+X+E
bindkey "^X^E" edit-command-line # binds CTRL+X - CTRL+E
```

Comment: Sweet, this is just what I was looking for! Thanks to all the other pretty good (and close) answers.

Comment: Added a little trick --- @Serg, i hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Rmano sure, that's a useful addition to the answer and will be helpful for others. Thank you !

Comment: Me too, I added the second binding so that it mimics exactly Bash's behavior, rephrase, rewrite etc;

Comment: This is really cool. Next step would be to say grab last 10 commands entered to refine into new command group.

Answer (score 13):

Use `gedit -`. This way it will read from stdin, so you can use

```
echo 'echo "complex command"'|gedit -
```

or simply

```
gedit - <<< 'echo "complex command"'
```

This way you won't need to create a separate tmpfile.

Answer (score 3):

With this command you can achieve that:
`echo "This is a complex command" > tempfile | gedit tempfile`.

**Edit:**

As I understand it, you want something like this:
`echo echo "This is a complex command" > tempfile | gedit tempfile`.
For example, `echo ls -d  > tempfile | gedit tempfile` will open a gedit file with the following text: "ls -d".

That said I would advice against editing commands on Gedit. The Linux terminal is extremely powerful(we have a powerful tab completion).

Comment: Thank you. Though, in Ubuntu 12.10 with the standard bash terminal this outputs `This is a complex command` in Gedit ... which is the output not the command itself.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean, you want to see this on Gedit: `echo "This is a complex command"` ?

Comment: Yes, so that I can edit the command further.

Comment: @somethis,  did that command do what you wanted? If so, could you kindly mark as answer(if it is indeed the answer you were looking for), please?

Comment: While this answer works, my suggestion is to write a bash script . You can then edit the script with any editor. For information on bash scripting see http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_writing_shell_scripts.php . Of course you can script with tools other then bash such as perl, php, awk ....

Comment: I agree 100% with @bodhi.zazen.

Comment: What I'm looking for is easy to do with a terminal based editor. Just that I would like to do it with gedit:
[http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/1446/rapidly-invoke-an-editor-to-write-a-long-complex-or-tricky-command](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/1446/rapidly-invoke-an-editor-to-write-a-long-complex-or-tricky-command)

Comment: Oh, I see. cool.