# How do we break an existing command already in history to multiple lines

Tags: command-line

Enter a very long command at shell. Now continue to up-arrow into history, tweak it, and make it a lot longer. At some point you're thinking: "I should have made this a multi-line command when I started". Well, now that the command is all just one line, is there a way to break it up?

Example:

```
foo | grep "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" | grep "bbbbbbbbbbbbbb" | more
```

Now to make that easier to continue editing:

```
foo |\    << enter some control character here to split the line
grep "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" |\
grep "bbbbbbbbbbbbbb" |\
more
```

In the above example, it wouldn't work to position the cursor after the pipe, enter backslash, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Nor <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, etc. Depending on the keystroke a new line does open with `>`, but it appears to be waiting for text which would follow the last character ( `more` above, rather than `foo |`).

The old fashioned way to get out of this situation is to copy the line (using the mouse or from `.history`), paste it into an editor, break it up and add the `\` EOL on each line, then copy/paste it back into the CLI. That's ugly-primitive.

Is there an easier way to break up a long line of multiple commands in the terminal?

Comment: If you want to make complex edits to the command, use an editor: https://askubuntu.com/a/708180/158442

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiline commands always will be archived in the command history as a single line. On the terminal prompt, you cannot edit a line to appear on multiple lines.

The approach to go about this is, is to open the command in your default editor. With the cursor sowewhere in your command, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>. This opens the command in your default editor (`nano` on Ubuntu), where you can do all your edits, including splitting the lines. In nano, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> to save the changes and close the editor: your command will immediately be executed.

Comment: Tried it, works perfectly. Re-editing a multi-line command also works. TYVM

Comment: Thanks, this is useful :-)